# Associated bundle - valued 1 forms.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, vector-bundles

Let $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ be a principal bundle with structure group $G$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$.

Fact: (as can be found in lecture notes [here](http://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/Lect1.pdf))

Functions $f_{\alpha}:U_{\alpha}\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ satisfying

\begin{align*}
f_{\alpha}(m)=\text{ad}_{g_{\alpha\beta}(m)}f_{\beta}(m),\quad m\in U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}
\end{align*}

define a section $\sigma\in\Gamma(\text{ad}P)$.

They then extend this idea on pg 11 and interpret the above fact as forms $\tau_{\alpha}\in \Omega^1(U_{\alpha};\mathfrak{g})$ satisfying

\begin{align*}
\tau_{\alpha}=\text{ad}_{g_{\alpha\beta}}\circ \tau_{\beta}
\end{align*}

determine forms in $\Omega^1(U_{\alpha};\text{ad}P)$.

I'm trying to get a better understanding of this extension. I can see it heuristically. The functions $f_{\alpha}$ take a point in $M$ and spit out a vector in $\mathfrak{g}$. Whereas the functions $\tau_{\alpha}$ take in a point in $M$ and a vector in $TM$ and spits out a vector in $\mathfrak{g}$, so it's natural to say this $\tau_{\alpha}$ then defines a form in $\Omega^1(U_{\alpha};\text{ad}P)$.

However, I really want to see a clear argument written down and am struggling to construct one.

Any ideas?

Thanks!